# Help improve my answers?

Tags: discussion

I hope this is the right forum.  I posted an answer to this post.
[Extremely low output from amplifier](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/122752/extremely-low-output-from-amplifier?noredirect=1#comment244406_122752)

Which I then saw was voted down.

Perhaps I was unintentionally rude?  I also didn't give a total answer, but was trying to teach a bit, by asking questions.  Is this wrong?

Perhaps I upset the poster and they voted me down?

Comment: Your answer looks reasonably written to me.  I didn't have time to read the (too long) question to be able to make sense of your answer, but nothing jumps out at me that explains the 2 downvotes.  Mysterious downvotes happen around here some times.  You can ask in a comment what someone objected to.

Comment: OK thanks, I didn't know if it was OK to ask why someone down voted...(mostly I just want to help, In some ways if they don't want to take my advice that's OK, but saying it was a bad answer.. well I was PO'ed and vented here.

Comment: I wouldn't ask just "why the downvote". That would probably get more downvotes for the attittude. You can ask what someone thought was wrong, misleading, or badly worded. Usually you don't get any answer, which then let's others see there is no real merit to the downvotes. I only downvote answers rarely. They have to be outright wrong, misleading, or very poorly written. But others have different standards, probably the same ones that think they are entitled to answers here and don't spend much time answering questions themselves.

Answer (score -1):

Other than the first sentence, which is more of a comment,  the rest seems fine. Those up votes and points don't necessarily mean what you think they mean ... It does happen that  the most upvoted and selected answer be out and out wrong, it is a consensus system after all. Of course the opposite also occurs, and way more often. Like wise you can get drive by down voting, it may very well have been caused by some other question in which you upset someone so they wanted to "make you pay".  There are certain people can always be trusted to do certain things, like downvote you on another question when you disagree with them.  On individual events it's hard to tell but there are patterns.

The key is to realize that it's a ying and yang thing and don't focus on the points so much.